# Keyboard Overlapping with Entry Xamarin.froms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a Xaml page with Entry Field. Keyboard is overlapping Entry Field when I am trying to enter value in Entry in Xamarin.froms

Comment: please post more information. An image and the xaml file causing you issues. It's impossible to help otherwise

Comment: there is a plugin for this for iOS https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap

Comment: can you post the xaml code with screen shot for better understanding.

Answer (score 9):

Check your Entry is inside a ScrollView

Answer (score 4):

There is a good solution for this issue:

At your MainPage.xaml:

```
//we could use any layout
<StackLayout x:Name="MainStackLayout">...</StackLayout>
```

Add helper for layouts:

```
public static class LayoutHelper
    {
        public static void SetLayoutPosition(this Layout layout, bool onFocus, int x = 0, int y = 0, uint length = 50)
        {
            if (onFocus)
            {
                layout.TranslateTo(x, y, length, Easing.Linear);
            }
            else
            {
                layout.TranslateTo(x, y, length, Easing.Linear);
            }
        }
    }
```

At your constructor in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
this.MainStackLayout.Focused += (s, e) => { this.CentralGrid.SetLayoutPosition(onFocus: true, y: -300); };
this.MainStackLayout.Unfocused += (s, e) => { this.CentralGrid.SetLayoutPosition(onFocus: false); };
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a know bug in Android (with xamarin)...

Create a new class in Android project like this (with this name)

```
public class AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid
    {
        private readonly View mChildOfContent;
        private int usableHeightPrevious;
        private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;

        public static void assistActivity(Activity activity, IWindowManager windowManager)
        {
            new AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid(activity, windowManager);
        }

        private AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid(Activity activity, IWindowManager windowManager)
        {

            var softButtonsHeight = getSoftbuttonsbarHeight(windowManager);

            var content = (FrameLayout)activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
            mChildOfContent = content.GetChildAt(0);
            var vto = mChildOfContent.ViewTreeObserver;
            vto.GlobalLayout += (sender, e) => possiblyResizeChildOfContent(softButtonsHeight);
            frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)mChildOfContent.LayoutParameters;
        }

        private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent(int softButtonsHeight)
        {
            var usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
            if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious)
            {
                var usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.RootView.Height - softButtonsHeight;
                var heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;
                if (heightDifference > (usableHeightSansKeyboard / 4))
                {
                    // keyboard probably just became visible
                    frameLayoutParams.Height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference + (softButtonsHeight / 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    // keyboard probably just became hidden
                    frameLayoutParams.Height = usableHeightSansKeyboard;
                }
                mChildOfContent.RequestLayout();
                usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
            }
        }

        private int computeUsableHeight()
        {
            var r = new Rect();
            mChildOfContent.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            return (r.Bottom - r.Top);
        }

        private int getSoftbuttonsbarHeight(IWindowManager windowManager)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                var metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
                int usableHeight = metrics.HeightPixels;
                windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetRealMetrics(metrics);
                int realHeight = metrics.HeightPixels;
                if (realHeight > usableHeight)
                    return realHeight - usableHeight;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

And then in the MainActivity (OnCreate) write this...

```
// Fix the keyboard so it doesn't overlap the grid icons above keyboard etc, and makes Android 5+ work as AdjustResize in Android 4
            Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                // Bug in Android 5+, this is an adequate workaround
                AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid.assistActivity(this, WindowManager);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Make sure you did not apply Translations to your views](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3403). If you did, you can temporarily undo them like this:

```
foreach (Entry entry in entries)
{
    entry.Focused += (a, b) =>
    {
        TranslatedView.TranslationY = 0;
    };
    entry.Unfocused += (a, b) =>
    {
        TranslatedView.TranslationY = initialTranslation;
    };
}
```

The Focused/Unfocused events are the closest you can get to OnSoftKeyboardAppearing/Disappearing.

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty common issue.

**For IOS** you can use this Plugin (add to your IOS project):
https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap

In your iOS project call (in AppDelegate.cs):

```
Xamarin.Forms.Init();//platform specific init
KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init ();
```

You must do this AFTER you call Xamarin.Forms.Init().

**For Android:** You can add the SoftInput setting on your MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan, Label = "@string/app_name", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/SplashActivity", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait) ]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

...
```

Comment: This has always worked for me on Android, but since the latest XF version (2.3.3) this doesn't work anymore. The whole behaviour of resizing the page when the keyboard gets activated seems to be changed. Any new solutions available?