# Keyboard overlapping the entry fields

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, keyboard

i have a view which contains entry fields kept inside the scrollView,here when i tapped on entry field the keyboard popups and covers the remaining fields,by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761370/keyboard-overlapping-with-entry-xamarin-froms) i couldnt able to solve my problem.i chnged my main activity as `[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]` and also checked for `AdjustPan` nothing worked,how to scroll those fields upto last field when keyboardpopups?

```
<ContentView>
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
  <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="10">
    <StackLayout.Spacing>
      <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone = "8" Tablet ="16"/>
    </StackLayout.Spacing>
    <Entry x:Name="FirstNameEntry" PlaceholderColor="#9E9E9E" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Placeholder="First name" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="#191919" FontFamily="Avenir Book">
      <Entry.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="45" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
      </Entry.HeightRequest>         
    </Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="LastNameEntry" Text="{Binding LastName}" PlaceholderColor = "#9E9E9E" Placeholder="Last name" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="#191919" FontFamily="Avenir Book">
      <Entry.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="45" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
      </Entry.HeightRequest>         
    </Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="MobileNameEntry" Keyboard="Numeric" PlaceholderColor="#9E9E9E" Text="{Binding MobileNumber}" TextChanged = "On_PhoneNumberTextChanged" Placeholder="Mobile number" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="#191919" FontFamily="Avenir Book">
      <Entry.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="45" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
      </Entry.HeightRequest>         
    </Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="HouseNumberEntry" Text="{Binding HouseNumber}" PlaceholderColor="#9E9E9E" Placeholder="House number" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="#191919" FontFamily="Avenir Book">
      <Entry.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="45" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
      </Entry.HeightRequest>
    </Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="StreetNameEntry" Text="{Binding StreetName}" PlaceholderColor="#9E9E9E" Placeholder="Street name" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="#191919" FontFamily="Avenir Book">
      <Entry.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="45" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
      </Entry.HeightRequest>
    </Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="CityNameEntry" Text="{Binding City}" PlaceholderColor="#9E9E9E" Placeholder="City" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="#191919" FontFamily="Avenir Book">
      <Entry.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="45" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
      </Entry.HeightRequest>
    </Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="PostCodeEntry" Text="{Binding PostalCode}" PlaceholderColor="#9E9E9E" Placeholder="Post code" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="#191919" FontFamily="Avenir Book">
      <Entry.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="45" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
      </Entry.HeightRequest>
    </Entry>
    <Picker x:Name="AddressTypePicker" Title="Select type" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" SelectedIndexChanged="AddressTypePicker_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
      <Picker.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="40" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="45" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
      </Picker.HeightRequest>
    </Picker>
  </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#f2c646" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" Padding="0">
    <StackLayout.HeightRequest>          
      <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="40" Android="50" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="50" Android="60" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
    </StackLayout.HeightRequest>
    <StackLayout Padding="10">
      <Label Text="Cancel" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontFamily="Avenir Book" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnCancelBtnClicked"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <Label.FontSize>              
          <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="15" Android="17" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="20" Android="22" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
        </Label.FontSize>
      </Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="10">
      <Label Text="Save" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Avenir Book">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <Label.FontSize>
          <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="15" Android="17" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="20" Android="22" WinPhone="28" />
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
        </Label.FontSize>
      </Label>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a situation of signup form. Why don't you use tableview with `Intent="Form"` as table view has a built-in scroller which can accommodate for keep-entry-in-view behaviour. It gives native look of a form as well.

I used it in one of my projects and it worked perfectly on both iOS and Android.

```
<TableView Intent="Form" HasUnevenRows="true">
</TableView>
```

Reference: [TableView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/)

Hope this helps